# Button.click() freezes (no timeout)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, freeze

I'm new in selenium and I'm working on one web page. The problem is that sometimes, there is a situation when button.click() freezes and raise no exception but does not continue neither, just freeze and nothing happens.

Do you know how to avoid that? Or how to set some `timeout` to raise an `exception` if it takes more than x seconds?

Another solution would be to measure a time of execution but I'm not sure if it is not an overkill and don't know what to do.

```
button = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-rgt.active a')
log('NEXT LINE: button.click()') # I CAN SEE THIS IN THE LOG FILE (line at the bottom)
button.click()
log('BUTTON CLICKED') # I DONT SEE THIS IN THE LOG FILE
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? Is it reproducible in both chrome and firefox?

Comment: Also, what selenium version?

Comment: @alecxe I use PhantomJS. The problem is that I can't figure out whether is it reproducible because this situation happens randomly and quite rare (1 in hour maybe). I will check selenium version and let you know but it should be the newest.

Comment: Oh yeah, wonderful world of PhantomJS, I remember. One thing to try: `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)` instead of `button.click()`.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Is it possible to set something like Timeout to the click() method? Built-in or not.

Comment: @alecxe The command you wrote seems not work. Traceback is here: http://pastebin.com/s5rKkF8h The button is a tag.

Answer (score 1):

The element is most likely not being found and the script is continuously looking for the element. There are a few different types of time outs you can set: Implicit and Explicit

Explicitly waiting will wait for an "Expected Condition". You can read more on this at [SeleniumHQ](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

You can also set an Implicit wait which will wait a given amount of time before throwing an exception, again you can read more at SeleniumHQ.